# Is $n=6$ the only integer satisfies ${\sigma}_x(n) \equiv 0\bmod{n}$ for every odd integer $x > 0$ and $2 (\bmod n)$ if $x$ is even integer?

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors, perfect-numbers, congruences, infinite-divisibility

After a few computations in wolfram alpha about the divisor function for some values of $n$ to look the behavior of $\sigma_x(n)\bmod n$ for $\,n=6,\,$ i got this result : $\sigma_x(6)=0 \bmod 6$ for $x$ odd and 2 mod 6 if $x$ is even

**Edit:01** :${\sigma}_x(n) =\sum_{d|n} d^x$ is the sum divisor function

**Note:01**:I edited the question just to define the sum divisor function

**My question here** :

Is $n=6$ the only integer satisfies $\sigma_x(n)
\equiv 0\bmod n$ for every odd integer  $x > 0$  and $2 \bmod n$ if $x$ is even integer ? and if it is how do i show this ?

**Note :02**:I want to know more about periodicity of the divisor function

Thank you for any help

Comment: You need to fix these $\LaTeX$ errors.

Comment: Ok, I fixed $\LaTeX$. Now you need to fix typos, and if you can help it, also English or logic ("logic" in the everyday sense). *** Short sentences would help a lot (as well as avoiding pronouns).

Comment: You did not compute enough terms. sigma 23 of 6 is twice a square, so sigma 24 of 6 is odd.  Gerhard "Check The OEIS Each Time" Paseman, 2016.01.02

Comment: Also, you need to sharpen your formulation to exclude trivial answers such as: " If x is such a number, so is sigma(sigma(x)).", as well as what evidence you use precisely to base your conjecture (which seems to be not many iterates).  It is unclear that sigma possesses any periodicity properties modulo any large integer, and you should perform more tests before posting a question like that in the title.  Gerhard "Think Some More Before Asking" Paseman, 2016.01.02.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman, I don't meant iterating sum divisor function ,pleas check this :sigma_23(6)mod6=0 is not twice :http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sigma_23%286%29mod6

Comment: check :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function, to see what kind of sigma_k(n) which i meant :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function

Comment: Sorry for my confusion.  For sum of (power of) divisors function, you can use the multiplicative property in showing periodicity in x, and you have the natural subproblem of showing for which  $n $ is $\sigma_3(n)$ a multiple of $n$.  Have you done that or something like that?  Gerhard "Then Look At Two Next" Paseman, 2016.01.02.

Comment: The problem how to show it's the only  integer who has the property

Comment: @GerhardPaseman,i have showed it is verified using multiplicative properties of sigma ,i got ,\sigma_x{6}=(2^x+1)(3^x+1) and this is easy to check it is 0 mod 6 if x is odd and 2 mod 6if k is even , but the problem now which i challenged is to show that is n=6 the only integer who is satisfies  this if the conjecture was true !!!! Rafik ,RH

Comment: "for $x$ odd and $2 \bmod 6$ if $x$ is even" ... or simply: for $x\equiv 2\bmod 6\ $? -- possibly my "translation" is not correct. However, it would not hurt to rewrite the same in a way which is easier to understand.

Comment: Your question: "for every odd integer $x$ ... if $x$ is even integer" is hard for me to comprehend.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński, my interpretation is that for fixed n, (sigma_k(n) mod n) is periodic  in k, and for n=6 the sequence has a period of 2.  Does any other n produce a sequence of period 2? Rafik conjectures not, and my answer supports but does not prove his conjecture.  Gerhard "Ask Me If It's Unclear" Paseman, 2016.01.04.

Comment: Here and in many cases I feel that in addition to the "easy English" (:-) there should be also a formal formulation like $\ (\forall\exists(K\Rightarrow L))\Rightarrow A$ -- something like this. One may even introduce notation $E$ and $M$ for the sets of all positive even and, respectively, odd integers. (I gave up on down-voting a long time ago, but z.r. should not be surprised that someone did).

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński, my general question was :is there a fixed integer $n$ which satisfies :$\sigma_k(n)\equiv 0\bmod n$ for every postive integer $k $ ,since this it's a rare phonemona to happen as shown by many proofs gaven out by theorist of number theory , i have tried to find a good integer who is satisfies at a least for a large integers the property of multiperfect number this is reason which letting me to suppose it as it titled !!!! "Is RH has been proved ? "

Comment: Thank you. (My own name for "multiperfect numbers" is "baroque numbers". You and Gerhard may adopt my term, make me happy this new year :-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $r=\gcd(k,e+1)$, and $p$ a prime. Then $\sigma_k(p^e) \equiv r\frac{p^{e+1}-1}{p^r -1} \bmod \sigma(p^e)$. Also, $r=1$ if and only if $\sigma(p^e)$ divides $\sigma_k(p^e)$.  Thus for $k$ coprime to $\tau(n)$, we have $\sigma(n)$ divides $\sigma_k(n)$.  The relation also suggests that for a given $n$ the sequence $\sigma_k(n)\bmod \sigma(n)$ is periodic in $k$ with a period dividing $L$, the least common multiple of ($1+$ each exponent) in the prime factorization of $n$.  **Edit 2016.01.04**: Once can show a nonreduced representation $\sigma_k(n) = a_k\sigma(n)/b_k$ where the $b_k$ are integers not necessarily coprime to the integers $a_k$ or to $a_k\sigma(n)$, with the property that the $b_k$ are bounded and periodic with period $L$.  This is not enough to show $\sigma_k(n) \bmod \sigma(n)$ is periodic with small period, unfortunately. **End Edit 2016.01.04**.

If now $n$ is multiperfect (so $n$ divides $\sigma(n)$) we have $n$ divides $\sigma_k(n)$ for $k$ coprime to $\tau(n)$.  In particular if $\tau(n)$ is a power of $2$, then $n$ divides $\sigma_k(n)$ for all odd $k \gt 0$.

It is still possible that $n$ can divide $\sigma_k(n)$ for $k$ not coprime
to $\tau(n)$.  However if $L$ is not prime, it seems likely that there will be more than one nonzero value of $\sigma_k(n) \bmod \sigma(n)$.  If this is so, it would be one ingredient in a proof that 6 is the unique number having the titled properties, the other ingredient being that 6 is the only nontrivial multiperfect number with $L$ a prime.

**Edit 2016.01.10:** I botched an earlier edit which claimed that 6 is the only known multiperfect number $n$ which satisfies $\sigma_2(n) \bmod n = 2$.  It is true, but the analysis had some flaws.  However, one expects multiperfect numbers other than 1 and 6 to be a multiple of 4; when $n$ satisfies $\sigma(n) \bmod n = 0$ and $\sigma_2(n) \bmod n = 2$, and in addition $ n \bmod 4  = 0$, then all odd prime factors of $n$ except one must occur to an even multiplicity, and the remaining odd prime factor must occur to a multiplicity of 1 mod 4 and must be a prime that is 3 mod 4.  While simple, these observations say a lot about $n$ and suggest that any numbers satisfying the title congruences are rare indeed, perhaps more so than odd multiperfect numbers.  **End Edit 2016.01.10**

Gerhard "Mea Culpa, Mea Maxima Culpa" Paseman, 2016.01.03

Comment: I don't know why the downvote to my question

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted my answer.  It turns out that 6 is the only multiperfect number with L a prime.  So now it boils down to showing multiple nonzero values mod n for composite L.  Gerhard "Will Accept Downvotes With(in) Reason" Paseman, 2016.01.03

Comment: The key idea in showing $n=6$ is the only multiperfect number with $ L$ prime is to show all prime factors of $\sigma(n)$ and thus of $n$ are 0 or 1 mod $L$ all with multiplicity $L-1$, and thus $(L/(L-1))^{m+1} \geq \sigma(n)/n \geq L$, where $m$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$ that are 1 mod $L$. This quickly leads to $L=2$, and then showing the largest prime factor of $n$ must be at most one more than the second largest prime factor.  Gerhard "It's Nice When Things Simplify" Paseman, 2016.01.04

Comment: I should say prime factors of $n$ have the same multiplicity.  One has $\sigma(n)/n \geq L^{m+1-L}$ also.  Gerhard "Dislikes Running Out Of Time" Paseman, 2016.01.04

Comment: @ let $ e=1$ ,by the way you will get $\sigma_k(p)=p^k+1$ you have to get for any odd positive integer $r=gcd(k,e+1)=1$ which $k$ (odd)   is coprime to $t(n)$  it follows that $\sigma(p)=p+1$ never devides $\sigma_k(p)=p^k+1)$ for all odd positive integer $k $,(* I think to suppose that :e must greater than 1) !!!!

Comment: 2+1 divides 2^3 + 1,  3+ 1 divides 3^5 + 1, 7+1 divides 7^11 + 1.  So if e=1, p+1 divides p^(2k+1) + 1. Gerhard "Sometimes Confuses Odd And Even" Paseman, 2016.01.04